# Fade-in on scroll fades everything instead of 1 by 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm using a fade in animation, so that when the object comes in completely visible in the window, it fades in. However, as soon as the first object fades in, everything else fades in as well, making the desired effect obsolete.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.hideme').each(function(i) {

      var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
      var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 1500);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post-preview">
  <div class="hideme">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="post-title">The night sky is more than beauty</h3>
      <h4 class="post-subtitle">If looking into the sky is not pretty enough...</h4>
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Ricardo Castillo</a> on September 2, 2016 at UTSA</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-preview">
  <div class="hideme">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="post-title">Your account has been compromised</h3>
      <h4 class="post-subtitle">Mr. Robot inspired; cyber security fears</h4>
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Ricardo Castillo</a> on August 9, 2016 at UTSA</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-preview">
  <div class="hideme">
    <a href="#">
      <h3 class="post-title">Why the future scares me</h3>
      <h4 class="post-subtitle">A technological perspective to the future</h4>
    </a>
    <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Ricardo Castillo</a> on September 3, 2016 at UTSA</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't find what's wrong with this, and would very much appreciate a hand.

Comment: This appears to work for me here:  https://jsfiddle.net/gyjgqdLn/ (you can resize the window which the page renders into so you can scroll.

Comment: It sort of does? Everything fades it at once though; I'm trying to fade in one at a time, according to visibility.

Comment: I notice with this that using the mousewheel to scroll with, it seems to work, but as soon as I drag the scrollbar down, everything appears at once... (edit: nevermind, same working behaviour on both)

Comment: I kind of figured already the script does work, but the sizes grabbed by the script were too high. I decreases them a little bit and approaches more the desired effect. It was always there, but barely visible that I didn't notice.

Answer (score -1):

This works, however the script values taken are too high. Eliminating the sum of the window height gets closer to the desired effect. It was always working, just barely visible.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer :-)